# WSO2 API Manager integration with Oracle Identity Manager

Tags: identity, wso2-api-manager

We are using WSO2 API Manager as a gateway to route requests to backend. We have a requirement to verify user credentials and authorization by making a call to Oracle Identity Manager and Oracle Access Manager before making the call to the backend. 
I have read the external LDAP user store configuration. But my client's enterprise is using Oracle identity management for user and access management. 
How can this be done in WSO2 API manager.

Answer (score -1):

With the current version of API-M which is 1.8.0, we can not add an external Identity Manager as the OAuth server for API Authorization. This sort of an integration will be possible with the next release of WSO2 API Manager which is 1.9.0.

However, you can integrate an external Identity Provider for user authentication by leveraging the capabilities of WSO2 Identity Server. You could integrate WSO2 API Manager with WSO2 Identity Server and user that for SSO and integrate with an external IDP. Please read this [blog](http://pushpalankajaya.blogspot.com/2014/07/leveraging-federation-capabilities-of.html) on how to achieve that.